# Get current international time, not a device time using(api) via internet in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I want to get current international time using internet in React Js

```
const date = new Date();
```

It basically get the current device time. But i do not want this.
When i change my device time, it also changed automatically(`date`).

Please suggest any good time zoon api for React js?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

have you tried moment.js? Its a formatter for dates.

Comment: Yes I tried it. But when i change my device local time, it also changed automatically. Do you give any example related to the time zone to get international time?

Comment: Now i am using http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now to get global time.

Comment: moment.js uses device time, not the correct time in the internet.